# 3D array and populate each cell in the array with the product of the indexes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I was learning javascript right now and I came across this question:

[Sample Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z11WX.png)

What i want to do is takes 3 number as input and generate a 3d array based on the input. Populate each cell in the array with the product of the indexes.

I can't figure it out. Appreciate your help

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is only what I have for now a 2 d array:
`code`
let x = [
[0, 1],
[2, 3]
];

// access the first item 
console.log(x[0]); // [0, 1]

// access the first item of the first inner array
console.log(x[0][0]); // 0 `code`
im not familiar with 3d arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach

```js
function create3DArray (a, b, c) {
    const matrix = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        matrix[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = [];
            for (let k = 0; k < c; k++) {
                matrix[i][j][k] = i * j * k;
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

console.log(create3DArray(2, 2, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks you @Abito Prakash, btw where this scenario occur ? "populate each cell in the array with the product of indexes"

Comment: In the line `matrix[i][j][k] = i * j * k;` we are populating each cell with product of indices

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create another way for this question:

```js
// Variables
var array;

var input1;
var input2;
var input3;

// To understand how works it
/*
    array[0][0][0] = "0,0,0"
    array[0][0][1] = "0,0,0"
    array[0][1][0] = "0,0,0"
    array[0][1][1] = "0,0,0"
    array[1][0][0] = "0,0,0"
    array[1][0][1] = "0,0,0"
    array[1][1][0] = "0,0,0"
    array[1][1][1] = "0,0,0"
    */

function createArray() {
  array = new Array(input1);
  for (let x = 0; x < input1; x++) {
    array[x] = new Array(input2);
    for (let y = 0; y < input2; y++) {
      array[x][y] = new Array(input3);
    }
  }
}

function putArrayProductValues() {
  for (let x = 0; x < input1; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < input2; y++) {
      for (let z = 0; z < input3; z++) {
        array[x][y][z] = x * y * z;
      }
    }
  }
}

function viewArrayForm() {
  let string = "[";
  for (let x = 0; x < input1; x++) {
    string += "[";
    for (let y = 0; y < input2; y++) {
      string += "[";
      for (let z = 0; z < input3; z++) {
        string += array[x][y][z];
        if (z != input3 - 1) {
          string += ",";
        }
      }
      string += "]";
    }
    string += "]";
  }
  return string;
}

function execute() {
  input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;

  createArray();
  putArrayProductValues();

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = viewArrayForm();
}

// To understand
function putArrayValues() {
  for (let x = 0; x < input1; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < input2; y++) {
      for (let z = 0; z < input3; z++) {
        array[x][y][z] = x.toString() + "," + y.toString() + "," + z.toString();
      }
    }
  }
}

function showArray() {
  for (let x = 0; x < input1; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < input2; y++) {
      for (let z = 0; z < input3; z++) {
        console.log(array[x][y][z]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="padding: 5% 5%">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="form-label">Input 1: </label>
    <input id="input1" type="number" min="0" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="form-label">Input 2: </label>
    <input id="input2" type="number" min="0" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="form-label">Input 3: </label>
    <input id="input3" type="number" min="0" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 1%;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="execute()">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 5%;">
    <label class="form-label">Output: </label>
    <h3 id="output"></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```